# Are there other SharePoint 2013 services that require classic authentication?

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth, office-integration, office-web-apps, ntlm

Reading Crawler authentication in SharePoint 2013 for STS based external website I found that NTLM is still required in SharePoint 2013 for Search Crawls.

Are there other services that still require NTLM? I believe in SharePoint 2010 things like InfoPath Forms Services, Access Services, PerformancePoint, support for older, unpatched Office Clients and Excel Services may have.

I'm not sure if the switch to the new Office Web Apps Farm and other back end changes from 2010 to 2013 removed other requirements beyond search crawl.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling with getting Powerpivot working.  This article says it requires classic mode auth enabled on the web app:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210621.aspx

I'm still running this to ground though, I want to make sure that if I have windows claims with kerberos enabled and configure the c2wts to allow kerberos delagation (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2722087) that it still doesn't work.

EDIT:

I finally got it working on my dev box for refreshing sharepoint data.  Basically I was running into the double hop issue and by installing SSAS onto a SharePoint app server in the farm, that removed the second hop for refreshing SharePoint data.

I haven't finished my kerberos test yet but hopefully that will happen soon.

I also found this article:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15274.using-claims-authentication-across-the-microsoft-bi-stack.aspx

Which states:

> However, as of SharePoint 2013 with PowerPivot 2012 SP1, PowerPivot supports Claims-enabled Web Applications with Windows Claims identities. PowerPivot does support non-Windows claims, such as SAML, with limited functionality.